# generating jacoco code coverage for remote server

Tags: docker

I will explain the scenario which I got struck.
  I have made the B2B setup through docker image which I cant access because it is remote one.I want to generate the code coverage using jacoco in jenkins.Now I want to do everything in docker host.Before running testng data ,I need to update the wrapper file for the integration server to get the report. how to get the exec data and instrumented classes to get the code coverage in the remote location.

Comment: Hi Prasanth, please provide a clear question, what you have tried, where you are stuck, what did not work, which tools are you using, etc. Based on the current information I would not know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

In my server,I have already compiled class files.I am using tcp remote server mode to collect the data.I want the code coverage for those two class files and I have included those but am getting zero percentage code coverage.I am using external port corresponding to the tcp internal port to collect the data.